# Find files, rename them using "uuidgen" and add extension

Tags: files, find, rename

I have a list of files in a certain folder without extenstion. I want to rename them and add an extension. The name should be UUID. I know how to find them and there's the utility "uuidgen" for generating UUID, how can I do the rest?

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' # ??? -exec .... ???
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(uuidgen).ext"' Renamer {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find . -type f -name 'file*' -execdir ... \;`

  This part you appear to be familiar with: it finds files whose names match the glob `file*` and runs the command `...` on them where, in our case, `...` is replaced by:
- `sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(uuidgen).ext"' Renamer {}`

  This starts a shell, runs a mv command, and makes the file name available as `$1`.  (`Renamer` is an arbitrary string that the shell assigns to `$0` which the shell would use if it generates an error message.)  The `find` command replaces `{}` with the name of the file it found and this is what the shell assigns to `$1`.  Let's look just at the shell command:
- `mv "$1" "$(uuidgen).ext"`

  This renames the file from `$1` to a name created by `uuidgen`.

  Because the file name might contain spaces or other difficult characters, we place `$1` in double-quotes to protect the name from word splitting or shell expansions.

We used `-execdir` instead of `-exec` for two reasons:

1. It makes the `mv` command easier: it takes no extra code to make sure that the renamed file stays in the same directory.
2. `-execdir` is safer: if a directory were renamed *while* the `find` command was running, `-exec`, but not `-execdir`, can fail badly.

#### Why start a new shell?

It might be tempting to try to use:

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' -execdir mv {} "$(uuidgen).ext" \; # Don't do this
```

The issue here is that `uuidgen` would be run only once.  The shell would run `uuidgen` *before* it even starts the `find` command.  As a consequence, all `mv` commands will have the *same* target file name.  We want `uuidgen` to be run one time for *every* file that is found by `find`.  That is why we need to run `mv` and `uuidgen` under the `sh` command.

#### More efficient version

The above starts a new shell for each file found.  The following approach, by contrast, can process many thousands of files per shell process started:

```
find . -type f -name 'fi*' -execdir sh -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "$(uuidgen).ext"; done' Renamer {} +
```

Comment: what's `Renamer`?

Comment: The shell assigns the first argument, `Rename` in this case, to `$0` which the shell would use as the script name if the shell had to generate an error message.  If you don't care about possible error messages and just want to shorten the command, you could replace `Renamer` with `_`.

Comment: thanks. why not "exec" instead of "execdir"?

Comment: and I should also add `"$(uuidgen)".my_extenstion` correct?

Comment: @Johshi (a) I added the -exec vs -execdir explanation to the answer.  (b) Yes, if you want a file extension, you can add it to the file name like you suggest.

Comment: Why start a new shell? Couldn't you just do `-execdir mv {} "$(uuidgen).ext" \;`? Is this just to get better error messages?

Comment: @Bakuriu That is subtle: `-execdir mv {} "$(uuidgen).ext"` would mean that `uuidgen` would be run _once_ by the shell before `find` starts.  So, the same name would be used as the target for all files, _likely causing lots of files to be overwritten_.  Using the shell, with the shell command in single-quotes, as in the answer, causes `uuidgen` to be run for each file that is to be renamed.  So, as desired, all the files get different names.

Comment: @John1024 Ah, yes, sure.

Comment: Really nice answer, but even after looking in `man sh`, I could not find any reference or doc likely to act as a more detailed tutorial for the ` Renamer {} ` part of yr one liner... I had never seen it before and I still can't wrap my brain around that particular syntax.... Any reference ? Cheers.

Comment: @Cbhihe The `{}` is part of the `find` command, not `sh`: it tells `find` where to put the file names.  As for the `Renamer` part, it is documented, albeit tersely, as part of the explanation of the shell's option `-c`.  As for why use `Renamer` instead of some other string, the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866883/how-to-use-positional-parameters-with-bash-c-command/) may be helpful.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks, it had escaped me, and, yes, it IS terse. ----  `sh -c  [options] 'cmd_string' [cmd_name [argument ...]]` ""reads cmd(s) from the cmd_string operand instead of from the standard input. Special parameter 0 will be set from the cmd_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands."" ... the which also explains where you got yr `$1` from. Great. I just learnt something useful and it's only 11:13 am. ;-). Thanks for the nudge !

Comment: One more question though: when you invoke `sh -c '...' ` after an `find blabla -exec/execdir` you create a subshell `sh etc.` for each found file. That shell in turn spawns a subshell with its command string operand `mv etc`. So `find` passes `{}` down to the shell `sh`, which in turn passes `$0, $1, ... ` down to its spawned subshell `mv etc.` based on the syntax quoted from `man sh` above. Is it the correct way of interpreting that syntax in human ?

Comment: @Cbhihe Yes, that is about it except that the word _subshell_ has a specific meaning and `mv` is a spawned process but it is not _subshell_ nor does it run _in_ a subshell.   Separately, if efficiency is a concern, I added code to the answer that runs only one shell for every several thousand files found.

Comment: +1 I did mean to write sub-process mv ... etc.. My bad. If I could upvote you more than once, I would. Also the for loop provides an excellent way to spare cycles on very large jobs. I was going to post a question on that actually.